# How to reference exact value of a cell in matplotlib.table?

Tags: python, matplotlib, cell

I am using matplotlib table to print 'n' squared board and fill them with random choice of 'X' and 'Y'. However, I don't know and I failed to find this in the documentation, how to find the value (text) of the particular element of the table.

```
def table(data):
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_axis_off()
tb = Table(ax)

nrows, ncols = data.shape
width, height = 1.0 / ncols, 1.0 / nrows

# Add cells
for (i,j), val in np.ndenumerate(data):
    tb.add_cell(i, j, width, height, text=random.choice('XY'), loc='center', facecolor='none')
    print(i, j)
ax.add_table(tb)
return fig
```

I want to write if the two previous and two cells above are 'X', force writing 'Y' instead of random choice.

I tried to debug using:

```
print(tb[i][j])
```

But it failed to work. My goal is to have something like this:

```
if(tb[i-2]=='X' and tb[i-1]=='X' and tb[j-2]=='X' and tb[j-1]=='X'):
tb.add_cell(i, j, width, height, text='y'
else
tb.cell(I,j, text=random_choice(X,Y)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the API for a table: https://matplotlib.org/api/table_api.html

When you create a cell you are passing text as a parameter, but when you are trying to check whether an element i.e `tb[i-2]=='X'` you are not referencing the instance of the text.

Therefore it should be `tb[i-2].get_text() == 'X'` which will return the cell Text value.

**In relation to comment below:**

You'll probably want to create a magic method to access the data of the table.

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.values[key]

tb.__getitem__(i-2)
```

Comment: When I wrote:     

for (i,j), val in np.ndenumerate(data):
        if (tb[i-2].get_text() == 'X' and tb[i-1].get_text() == 'X'):
            tb.add_cell(i, j, width, height, text='Y', loc='center')
        else:
            tb.add_cell(i, j, width, height, text=random.choice('XY'), loc='center')

I've received following error:
TypeError: 'Table' object does not support indexing


Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!